# How to re-partition the data using Spark on no ephemeral storage?

Tags: java, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

I am running Spark on Kubernetes cluster. While re-partitioning data with many partitions, forcing it to have only 1 file per partition, I am getting my pods evicted.

The error is as following:

```
The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container sosreport-spark-cluster-opendatahub-w was using 56291400Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.
```

My Spark configs are:

```
def create_spark_config(spark_cluster, executor_memory='16g', executor_cores='4', max_cores='16'):
    print('Spark cluster is: {}'.format(spark_cluster))
    sc_conf = (
        pyspark.SparkConf().setMaster(spark_cluster) \
        .set('spark.driver.host', HOSTNAME) \
        .set('spark.driver.port', 42000) \
        .set('spark.driver.bindAddress', '0.0.0.0') \
        .set('spark.driver.blockManager.port', 42100) \
        .set('spark.executor.memory', '1536M') \
        .set('spark.executor.cores', '2') \
        .set('spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader', True) \
        .set('spark.kubernetes.memoryOverheadFactor', '0.20')
    )
    return sc_conf
```

This is how I am re-partitioning the data:

```
def save_repartitioned_dataframe(bucket_name, df):
    dest_path = form_path_string(bucket_name, repartitioned_data=True)
    print('Trying to save repartitioned data at: {}'.format(dest_path))
    df.repartition(1, "created_year", "created_month", "created_day").write.partitionBy(
        "created_year", "created_month", "created_day").mode("overwrite").parquet(dest_path)
    print('Data repartitioning complete with at the following location: ')
    print(dest_path)
    _, count, distinct_count, num_partitions = read_dataframe_from_bucket(bucket_name, repartitioned_data=True)
    return count, distinct_count, num_partitions
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem likely isn't the fact that you're using ephemeral storage but the fact that you're send your entire data to a single worker.

".repartition(1, "created_year", "created_month", "created_day")"

You're combining all of your data into a single spark partition which then writes to all partitions.

What you probably want todo is do a global sort by the partition key and then do a write.partionBy.  What this does is send most of the data to single table partition to a limited number of spark partitions. (typically a single spark partition if your partitions are small)

this typically looks like...

```
    df.orderBy("partitionCol")
      .write
      .partitionBy("partitionCol")
      .insertInto("my_table")
```

Comment: But this would not ensure 1 file per partition, right?

Comment: Also, I tried the above code with one change though: `df.orderBy("created_year", "created_month", "created_day").write.partitionBy(
        "created_year", "created_month", "created_day").mode("append").parquet(dest_path)`

It failed too.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava. it gives up the hard the 1 file limit and instead guarantees reasonably sized files. Generally if you have smaller partitions spark will pack it into one or two files.  with all of the files for the partition being in a folder.  Spark tends to work best when its operating on sets of files instead of single files.